# Is it possible to find a Thunder Stone before the Elite 4?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'm training my Eelektrik up to level 55 so I can use an Eelektross against the Elite 4. Is it possible to obtain a Thunder Stone before you go to the Battle Resort after becoming the Champion? If so, where?

Answer (score 3):

There is one inside [New Mauville](http://www.serebii.net/pokearth/hoenn/newmauville.shtml), accessible after defeating Groudon/Kyogre. Go to the center of Mauville City and speak to Wattson (who is in the centre plaza area), which will start the quest and give you access to New Mauville.

You can also receive Thunderstones by completing *Follow those fleeing goals!*, a [Secret Super Training](http://www.serebii.net/xy/supertraining.shtml) level.

If you fill your [secret base](http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/supersecretbases.shtml) with pals, Specifically Ninjas, Rich Boys, Pokemaniacs, Pokemon Ranger's, School kids or Street Thugs, each can unlock a skill to 'Search for Stones' - which can be used once per day to award you with any of the evolutionary stones.

Otherwise, there is a chance you will receive one as a reward from rematching Guitarist Dalton on [Route 118](http://www.serebii.net/pokearth/hoenn/route118.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is win the *Follow Those Fleeing Goals!*, a [Secret Super Training](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Super_Training#Secret_Super_Training) challenge.

You can also obtain one from the [Diving Treasure Hunter](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Diving_Treasure_Hunter) for a *Yellow Shard*.

Or you can win it from a [Inverse Battle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mauville_City#Inverse_Battle_Stop), but it's all about luck.

Comment: The easiest way to get multiple is through Super Training I agree, but if he's only looking for one, it's probably easier to talk to Wattson and enter New Mauville :)

Comment: If he has already defeated Groudon/Kyogre, yes. But I usually exploit Super Training for every evolutionary stone I need :)